# Avoid using Resource IDs in const fields - AGP 8.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've been getting this warning recently:
[image]

*Resource IDs will be non-final by default in Android Gradle Plugin version 8.0, avoid using them in **const fields***

This applies mostly to custom views, where I have declared drawables or colors that might be needed.

What would be the alternative for declaring these fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I upgraded to Android Gradle 8.0, it added this line automatically to my gradle.properties file:

```
android.nonFinalResIds=false
```

Which disables the feature and doesn't require any "migration" logic (the *const vals* don't have to be changed).

If you want to enable this flag, you'd have to remove the *const* modifier from all the variables that have a resource assigned to them.

Answer (score 0):

**In Android Studio**
for Optimize your build speed this message is appeared

```
Non-final resource IDs are currently disabled.
```

**Enable** non-final resource IDs for faster incremental compilation.

To enable, set `android.nonFinalResIds=true` in `gradle.properties`.

then **Sync Project** ...

Comment: Did your team experience faster incremental builds with enabling android.nonFinalResIds=true?